# PDOException: Cannot find driver but driver installed

Tags: mysql, ssl, pdo, php, remote-server

Similar questions exist but none help.

php5-fpm installation on Apache 2.4 connection to remote MySql database via SSL connection.

Can connect to MySQL via command line
`mysql -u myname -p'pass' -h xx.xx.xx.xx dbname`

Cannot connect to MySQL via php scripts.

```
define("DB_PASSWORD", $dbpass);
define("DB_DATABASE", $dbname);
define("DB_DSN", "mysql:host=$dbhost;dname=$dbname");
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
```

Returns an error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'`

Modules are loaded

```
php5-fpm -m  
...
PDO
pdo_mysql  
...

php5-fpm -i  
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => 5.5.43

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Is there something that is missing since
1)  php5-fpm runs on Port 9000, not a socket
2)  MySQL is on remote server Port 3306 & uses SSL

Grasping at straws here but cannot figure out why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Typo:  Live site has mysql.  Corrected above.

Answer (score 2):

Hate answering my own question but here is the answer in case others have a similar problem in the future.

Forgot the SSL certificates in the PDO request.
Added:

```
, array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem'
      )
```

to the constructor so

```
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem'
      )  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what problem with string `myql:host=$dbhost;dname=$dbname`, try `mysql` instead of `myql`